# How To Set OnClickListener (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, onclick

I know this is a very simple and maybe stupid question but I am having trouble putting an OnClickListener for my Floating Action Button. I have never done one for a button I did not make myself (Using a library) and I just need some help. Here is the code that I am using: https://gist.github.com/VirusThePanda/20320afd303150c02ea5

Here is the library that I am using for the button, and the source code I am using for the navigation bar. This might come in handy as it has a placeholder fragment that may be attached to the main activity.

Source: android-toolbar-with-drawer (From GitHub)
Library: android-floating-action-button (From GitHub)

Again, I am sorry for the very simple question. I am still learning Java and XML. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: My code is in the link in my post.

Comment: Post on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        android:id="@+id/multiple_actions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:onClick="fabClicked"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="#ec407a"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="#d81b60"
        fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>
```

Then, in your activity file (ie. in class custom_motivation), define the function fabClicked as :

```
...
public void fabClicked(View v){
  // write your code here ..
}
...
```

Comment: Okay, I go step by step. First, look what I have done, I have added a line `android:onClick="fabClicked"` in the <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu ... /> xml code snippet. This tells android that whenever this Button is clicked, go to a function named fabClicked, which must be defined by you in your activity. So, I have given the template for that too in my above answer. Now, once clicked what should happen ?? So, I have written in comments write your code here.., this indicates you telling android what it should do when someone presses your Floating Action Button. Simple !

Comment: Just on a side note ,setting onClick attribute inside xml is not considered as a good practice.