# My intent/ onClickListener doesn't work

Tags: android

My problem in short.

When user click my floating button he will be able to go to dial up screen and call phone number.**THIS DOESN'T WORK.**

I already have intent,in the same activity, where he will able to go to SMS screen and be able to send a text.**THIS WORKS JUST FINE.**

in first case nothing happened.If i put Toast in onClick listener also nothing happens.I just do not know why. Do i need to put another activity in my manifest? but this is not new activity?how to name it in my manifest....or problem is something completly different.

```
Well this is my full code:

    public class CetvrtaKnjiga extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.knjiga);

        PDFView pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        pdfView.fromAsset("diskretna.pdf").load();
        pdfView.enableSwipe(true);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.myFAB);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cetvrtaKinjigaIntent = new Intent(CetvrtaKnjiga.this, Narudzbina.class);
                startActivity(cetvrtaKinjigaIntent);
            }
        });

        FloatingActionButton fabKontakt = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.myFAB_kontakt);
        fabKontakt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "+3810629647169"));
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(CetvrtaKnjiga.this, "Radi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });
    }
}


my full xtml code:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pdfView">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/myFAB"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:src="@drawable/shopping_cart"
            app:elevation="5dp"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp" />


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/myFAB_kontakt"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:src="@drawable/phone"
            app:elevation="5dp"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/myFAB"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp" />
    </com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Really, no need to shout in bold font....

Comment: Stick a `Log.i()` statement in your click listener - do you see this log statement in your Logcat?

Comment: FYI - the more information you put in your question, the better and faster you'll get answers.  When you say it "doesn't work", what does happen?  Nothing? An error? Something else?  To @MichaelDodd 's point, what have you done so far to try to debug it?

Comment: Sorry but my level of frustation is so high right now...Nothing happens.Literally nothing. in my Logcat no comment of error.nothing

Answer (score 0):

Remove `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` flag.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "+3810629647169"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks pretty good.

Just make sure you are getting the reference of the "Floating Button" in the same class which is linked to the layout having "Floating Button" view and make sure the id of "Floating Button" in Java class and XML class is same.

Another thing if you are setting the listener in a "Fragment", then use "getActivity().startActivity(intent);"

There is a chance maybe you are setting the "ClickListener " to your "Floating Button" twice. Once with the code and second with empty braces. Make sure this is not the case. Because this happened to me once.

Still if it doesn't work then try the link given below:

[How To Set OnClickListener (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551322/how-to-set-onclicklistener-android)

Comment: Yes.... Has to be some minor mistake. Also check if you are not using setEnabed(false) or setFocusableInTouchMode(false) somewhere.